# URL Scheme is Installed in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, url, google-maps-mobile

I am Integrating Google Maps URL Scheme in my Application:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];
```

I am curios if there is some code to detect if Google Map isn't installed and redirect to App Store URL. Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it return true, that means the Google Map app has been installed.

```
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]])
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8"]];
else
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];
```

Comment: If it return true, that means the Google Map app has been installed.

Comment: such as if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) return YES; else return NO;

Comment: I am sorry that I am new to stack overflow. I don't know how to play around with it.

Comment: Thats Ok. If you need help in Stack Overflow check out the FAQ.